# Unable to store data from Facebook API

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have to retrieve a image path from graph api of Facebook. How would I store it into my locale storage? When I am using the locale storage onto a on complete method I'm getting a null to be store on the local storage.

```
private void getPhotoFromId(String photoId) {
        Log.d("Adapter" + "getPhotoFromId:-", photoId + "");
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/" + photoId, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                Log.d("Adapter Photo", response.toString());
                try {
                    JSONObject mObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject()));
                    JSONArray mArray = mObject.getJSONArray("images");
                    JSONObject imageObject = mArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    source = imageObject.getString("source");
                   prefHelper.savePref(Constants.IMAGE_SOURCE,source);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "images,picture");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

Comment: where you getting null exception

Comment: thank you for your quick reply i don`t getting a null exception the value  i  in shard prefrence(prefHelper) that would not be accessable outer this complete method .

Comment: have to initialized it ?

Comment: yes we have initialized

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should not add "/" in front of your ID.
Have you tried that in the Graph API in Facebook Developer site?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/

I couldn't find such field name "images,picture".

Comment: i`m getting right path but i`m not able to store in my data base

Comment: Have you succeeded parsing image in Graph API Explorer? I couldn't found such fields.

Comment: yes i`m getting a correct image path but i unable to store in a database

Comment: @pankajsoni You mean your path is correct, but you cannot parse the image path into "real" image? Then you should query image asynchronously via HTTP call. There's plenty of easy-to-use libraries. Try using Picasso library. http://square.github.io/picasso/